# Acumatica DeviceHub needs to be restarted every new row to the Print Jobs page (19.211.0011)

Tags: acumatica

Good day
We upgrade to the 19.211.0011 version of Acumatica. Now every time a new print job is added to the print jobs queue(SM206500) I have to restart the device hub so that the printer finds the new entries and then can print.

Any idea of how to get the device hub to detect that there are new jobs(prints) without needing to restart it?

Comment: Maybe you have it configured for polling and you're not waiting long enough until the next polling cycle. Try opening Configuration window and closing it, this should reset the cycle without wait too.

Comment: Had to update to a newer version of acumatica to fix this issue